# Optimization of fault diagnosis sequence using probability and cost

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, bayesian-network, sequence-analysis

I am developping the algorithm to optimize the fault diagnosis sequence using probability and cost.

For exemple, I have 3 diagnosis actions possibles :

option 1 : probability which can detect the root cause 20%, diagnosis cost 10

option 2 : probability which can detect the root cause 50%, diagnosis cost 50

option 3 : probability which can detect the root cause 30%, diagnosis cost 20

My purpose is to have a optimized the order of action sequence like option 1-3-2

Using theory of risk quantification, I calculated risk cost like cost x probability

However, when we choose option 1, I think we should consider also the possibility of next sequence (option 2 or option 3). And it is same if we choose another option as first.

How can I quantify also this possibility, to optimize the sequence order ?

Comment: Are the probabilities of success independent of each other?

Comment: @jblood94 Yes, we suppose that it is independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal order for the tests is the same as the order of the cost to price ratios.

Consider just two tests, $T_1$ and $T_2$ with probabilities $p_1$, $p_2$ and costs $c_1$, $c_2$. The sequence $\{T_1,T_2\}$ (i.e., first perform $T_1$, then if it fails to diagnose the root cause, perform $T_2$) has an expected cost equal to

$$p_1c_1+(1-p_1)(c_1+c_2)$$
$$=c_1+c_2-p_1c_2$$

Likewise, the expected cost for the sequence $\{T_2,T_1\}$ is:

$$=c_1+c_2-p_2c_1$$

For both sequences, the probability of a successful diagnosis is $1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)$, so the choice of sequence depends only on the expected cost. Notice that comparing the two expected costs is equivalent to comparing $c_1/p_1$
to $c_2/p_2$. Therefore, **a test with a lower cost to probability ratio should be performed before a test with a higher ratio**.

---

Applying this rule to the example tests given in the question, the optimal strategy would be:

1. Perform test 1 at a cost of 10 (cost/probability = 50). If test 1 detects the root cause, stop (20% of the time). If test 1 fails to detect the root cause, continue.
2. Perform test 3 at a cost of 20 (cost/probability ≈ 66.7). If test 3 detects the root cause, stop (24% of the time). If test 3 fails to detect the root cause, continue.
3. Perform test 2 at a cost of 50 (cost/probability = 100). The diagnostic sequence will end successfully on the third test 28% of the time. The diagnostic sequence will fail to identify the root cause 28% of the time.

The expected cost for this strategy is $0.2*10+0.24*(10+20)+0.56*(10+20+50)=54$. A strategy that performs the tests in any other order will result in a higher expected cost for the same overall probability of successful diagnosis (0.72).

---

Here's a simulation in R to check the rule on 7 tests using uniform random probabilities and costs:

```
library(RcppAlgos)
library(matrixStats)

n <- 7L # number of tests available
m <- permuteGeneral(n) # all permutations of test orderings
# 10k simulation replications
all(replicate(1e4, {
  mcost <- rowCumsums(array((cost <- runif(n))[m], dim(m)))
  mprob <- array((prob <- runif(n))[m], dim(m))
  # check that the lowest cost ordering is the same as the ordering of the c/p ratios
  identical( 
    m[which.min(rowSums(cbind(1, rowCumprods(1 - mprob[,-n]))*
                          cbind(mprob[,-n], 1)*mcost)),],
    order(cost/prob)
  )
}))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Very clear! But, if there are probability related with each action like ( 30% probability for success, 70% probability for failure of diagnosis--> we should do other diagnosis) , should we consider in different way ?

Comment: I may not understand your follow-up question, but the strategy outlined is for probabilistic outcomes. I updated the answer to hopefully clarify further.